# Do DEVc++ and Visual Studio have the same libraries?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, libraries, dev-c++

My script works perfectly with DEV-c++ but it does not work in Visual Studio. Someone told me it's because they don't use the same libraries, is this true?

Comment: It's not only the libraries, but Dev-C++ and Visual Studio use different compilers. Can you show the code in question please?

Comment: `DEV-c++` is an IDE. If you use `mingw` as the compiler in this IDE it will not be the same toolchain as Visual Studio. Output from different compilers (even different versions of the same compiler) is likely not to be compatible.

Comment: ***My script works perfectly with DEV-c++** Script? I assume you mean c++ application. c++ is not a scripting language. Or are you talking about some shell script used for building a project? The latter will certainly not work..

Answer (score 0):

Some libraries we can use in both compilers but there are libraries which Dev C++ is not supporting them but visual studio is supporting. So if you want to use wide range of libraries you have need to use visual studio.